# How to lock a table when selecting records return no data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Consider this table:

```
| id   | objId | fieldNumber |
|------|-------|-------------|
| 902  | 1     | 1           |
| 908  | 1     | 2           |
| 1007 | 1     | 3           |
| 1189 | 8     | 1           |
| 1233 | 12    | 1           |
| 1757 | 15    | 1           |
```

I want to enter a new record for a non existant obj. Lets say objId: 16. The field number must increase by 1 for every obj 16. Take a look at obj: 1. As you can see it increases by 1. Now if two or more database connections try to insert obj 16 at the same time I would have two obj 16 with fieldNumber 1. This cannot happen. I must guarantee the field numbers are not the same and must increase by one.

So my solution is get all records by objid. If there is at least one record then place a lock on all records by that objid then insert a record with the next fieldNumber.

Alternatively, when I get all records by objid. If there are no records then I will lock the whole table then insert a record with fieldNumber 1.

How would I go about placing a lock on the whole table? Let me know if you have a better idea to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you can handle exceptions, then probably the easiest way is to add a unique constraint on `(objid, fieldnumber)`.

Then you can run a query, such as:

```
insert into t(objid, fieldnumber)
    select @objid, coalesce(max(fieldnumber) + 1, 1)
    from t
    where objid = @objid;
```

If two simultaneous threads attempt to run the query, then the unique constraint will fail -- and the thread can re-try.

You can also use the SERIALIZABLE table hint (which is explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `objId` and `fieldNumber` together (should) form the primary key for this table. Normalized that way the constraint would be automatically enforced. I think this is a 'cleaner' solution. But if you can't drop an autonumbering PK scheme, then Gordon's solution is unbeatable.